# How to use groupby to take minute data and group by day?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df containing minute bars of different symbols like so:

```
                       timestamp    open    high      low   close  volume  trade_count        vwap symbol
0      2021-10-13 08:00:00+00:00  140.20  140.40  140.000  140.40    6084           65  140.205417   AAPL
1      2021-10-13 08:01:00+00:00  140.35  140.40  140.200  140.40    3052           58  140.308182   AAPL
2      2021-10-13 08:02:00+00:00  140.35  140.35  140.350  140.35     632           30  140.320934   AAPL
3      2021-10-13 08:03:00+00:00  140.28  140.30  140.200  140.20    2867           36  140.279473   AAPL
4      2021-10-13 08:04:00+00:00  140.20  140.20  140.200  140.20     435           36  140.199195   AAPL
...                          ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...          ...         ...    ...
58250  2021-10-27 19:58:00+00:00  209.31  209.33  209.215  209.26   26440          348  209.251852    ZTS
58251  2021-10-27 19:59:00+00:00  209.28  209.59  209.010  209.56  109758         1060  209.384672    ZTS
58252  2021-10-27 20:03:00+00:00  209.58  209.58  209.580  209.58  537786           49  209.580000    ZTS
58253  2021-10-27 20:05:00+00:00  209.58  209.58  209.580  209.58    4170            1  209.580000    ZTS
58254  2021-10-27 20:12:00+00:00  209.58  209.58  209.580  209.58     144            1  209.580000    ZTS

[58255 rows x 9 columns]
```

I want to be able to use `df.groupby` so I can loop over each of the days of each ticker. Something like:

```
                       timestamp    open    high      low   close  volume  trade_count        vwap symbol
0      2021-10-13 08:00:00+00:00  140.20  140.40  140.000  140.40    6084           65  140.205417   AAPL
1      2021-10-13 08:01:00+00:00  140.35  140.40  140.200  140.40    3052           58  140.308182   AAPL
2      2021-10-13 08:02:00+00:00  140.35  140.35  140.350  140.35     632           30  140.320934   AAPL
3      2021-10-13 08:03:00+00:00  140.28  140.30  140.200  140.20    2867           36  140.279473   AAPL
4      2021-10-13 08:04:00+00:00  140.20  140.20  140.200  140.20     435           36  140.199195   AAPL



                       timestamp    open    high      low   close  volume  trade_count        vwap symbol
0      2021-10-14 08:00:00+00:00  140.20  140.40  140.000  140.40    6084           65  140.205417   AAPL
1      2021-10-14 08:01:00+00:00  140.35  140.40  140.200  140.40    3052           58  140.308182   AAPL
2      2021-10-14 08:02:00+00:00  140.35  140.35  140.350  140.35     632           30  140.320934   AAPL
3      2021-10-14 08:03:00+00:00  140.28  140.30  140.200  140.20    2867           36  140.279473   AAPL
4      2021-10-14 08:04:00+00:00  140.20  140.20  140.200  140.20     435           36  140.199195   AAPL
```

How can I do this?

Someone suggested I look at another question, here:

```
table = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', axis=0, freq='D')).sum()
```

Which returns this:

```
Name: 2022-04-04 00:00:00+00:00, dtype: float64)
(Timestamp('2022-04-05 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='D'), open           0.0
high           0.0
low            0.0
close          0.0
volume         0.0
trade_count    0.0
vwap           0.0
Name: 2022-04-05 00:00:00+00:00, dtype: float64)
(Timestamp('2022-04-06 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC', freq='D'), open            2000.818300
high            2001.724000
low             2000.563300
close           2001.462900
volume         59717.000000
trade_count      487.000000
vwap            2001.073115
Name: 2022-04-06 00:00:00+00:00, dtype: float64)
```

**As I said I need to take my minute data and split the minutes into separate days. I don't need to upscale to daily bars.** Sorry if that was not clear!

Comment: Oh, you don't need to `.sum()` or anything like that. You can use `.apply()` or other methods and do whatever you want at that step.

Comment: BTW, you might want to switch your dataset to an example version for comprehensibility. Most of the columns here seem relatively unimportant, and the dates in the data you just added don't correspond with the ones in the snippet above. Check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Thanks mate, here's how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168449/how-to-loop-through-ohlc-minute-data-by-day/74172838#74172838